# approximation of law sines from spherical case to planar case

Tags: trigonometry, approximation, spherical-geometry

we know for plane triangle cosine rule is  $\cos C=\frac{a^+b^2-c^2}{2ab}$ and on spherical triangle is $ \cos C=\frac{\cos c - \cos a  \cos b} {\sin a\sin b}$ suppose $a,b,c<\epsilon$ which are sides of a spherical triangle, and $$|\frac{a^2 +b^2-c^2}{2ab}- \frac{\cos c - \cos a  \cos b} {\sin a\sin b}|<Ke^m$$

could any one tell me what will be $m$ and $K$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $x$ close to $0$, 
$$1-\frac{x^2}{2!} \le \cos x\le 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}$$
and 
$$x-\frac{x^3}{3!} \le \sin x\le x.$$
(We used the Maclaurin series expansion of $\cos x$ and $\sin x$.)

Using these facts on the small angles $a$, $b$, and $c$, we can estimate your difference.

Comment: could you be more specific? I have no Idea what is $O(x^4)$ or $x^3$. could you please write one more step and then I will try myself to get the $K$ and $m$

Comment: I have edited and written down explicit  inequalities.